# dispatch_async Reload UITableView not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

Sorry I'm noobs on Cocoa, since I'm new on iOS mobile development.. straight to the point, I've use GCD method on Cocoa to assign data to tableview but when I fire `[tableview reloadData]` it's not working. Here my sample code:

```
-(void)updateCell{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         NSIndexPath* indexPath;
        // Insert code to be executed on another thread here
        if(clean_data){
            for (int i=0; i<clean_data.count; i++) {
                indexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                sqCell *cell = (sqCell *)[stockQ cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                for (int j=0; j<plist.count; j++) {
                    NSString *a =[[clean_data objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1];
                    NSString *b =[[[plist objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0];
                    if([a isEqualToString:b]){

                        cell.last.text =[[clean_data objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1];
                        cell.change.text = @"1231231312312";

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Insert code to be executed on the main thread here
            ///reload table here
            [self reload];

        });
    });

}
```

here method to reload data

```
   -(void)reload{
    NSLog(@"reload");
    [stockQ setNeedsLayout];
    [stockQ setNeedsDisplay];
    [stockQ reloadData];

}
```

the console show **"reload"** text, but not firing stockQ UITableCiew.. what happen in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* do UI handling code in an async thread. Modifying the UI (like updating the tableView) - should *always* be done in the main thread. Try to pull that code from an async task and see if it works or not.
Another remark - why in any way do you need to reload the data in an async task? Table view is very lightweight & fast. All your code from the post should be ran within milliseconds. Use dispatch_async only for long running, time consuming tasks!

Comment: If I am not misreading the OP's code, they _are_ running the update on the main thread, to wit: `dispatch_get_main_queue()`. It shouldn't be a problem that it is asynchronous to the calling method - indeed, if that method is run on the main thread, it may have to be asynchronous to work (if the code is already in some event updating the table view).

Comment: Uhum. Did you notice that `cell.change.text = @"1231231312312";` is in the async thread?

Comment: can you give me an example.. or fixing my code above? because i really dont know how to do it :(

Comment: @nemesis don't worry about a downvote - but that said, it wasn't from me. Your answer is a bit unspecific and would benefit from the more specific explanation you gave in you rebuttal to my comment. It would also benefit from a bit of formatting (into 2 or 3 paragraphs?), so maybe the downvote is due to the overall impression of the answer?

Comment: It is upsetting that you try to help people and you get downvoted when you're right.
@vanbungkring just put all that code in the main thread, don't do that in an async thread.